# Observable with POST call in Angular2

Tags: angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I am using Angular2 in my application, And I saw advantages of using Observable while calling http calls. But somehow I am not able to make call when I am using Observable for POST requests, But it's working while GET request. If I use subscribe method, then POST is working.

Below is my code,

using Observable,

```
AddBreakoutsManually(breakoutUploads: Uploads): Observable<boolean> {
        console.log("Data = ", JSON.stringify(breakoutUploads));
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 

        return this.http.post("/breakout/InsertUploads", JSON.stringify(breakoutUploads), options)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
    }
```

Using subscribe,

```
Adding(breakoutUploads: Uploads) {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 

        this.http
            .post('/breakout/InsertUploads', JSON.stringify(breakoutUploads), options)
            .subscribe(data => {
                alert('ok');
            }, error => {
                console.log(error.json());
            });
    }
```

My API,

```
[HttpPost]
        public bool InsertUploads([FromBody]BreakoutUpload breakoutUploads)
        {
            return true;
        }
```

What mistake I am making while using observable in POST call ?

Comment: what is the error showing?

Comment: It was not showing any error, But somehow it starts working with same code :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what I changed, But it starts working with below code,

```
AddBreakoutsManually(breakoutUploads: Uploads): Observable<string> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 
    return this.http.post(Configuration.Url_AddBreakoutsManually, JSON.stringify(breakoutUploads), options) // ...using post request
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```